# GWT Maven dependencies

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have maven project Main and project Util.

Project Util depends on a third-party library Lib which depends on gwt-dev. gwt-dev causes a lot of conflicts, it is needed for GWT compilation only, so it should be marked as "provided", but it is "compile".

So I should mark Lib as "provided" in Util. But if I do so my Main project won't compile as it cannot find Lib classes.

At the moment I mark Lib as "provided" and then also include it as "provided" in Main. It is inconvenient because I have to remember Util dependencies.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Lib` in `compile` scope and [exclude](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) gwt-dev:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>Lib group</groupId>
      <artifactId>Lib artifact id</artifactId>
      <version>Lib version</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Just a remark, excluding is typically a bad practice. In this case, you don't have much choice, since `Lib`'s artifact should have `gwt-dev` as `provided` (it's `Lib`'s bug...). So, don't forget to add a decent comment that explains the exclusion.